# ANTLR4: wrong lexer rule matches

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm at a very beginning of learning ANTLR4 lexer rules. My goal is to create a simple grammar for Java [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) files. Here is what I have so far:

```
lexer grammar PropertiesLexer;

LineComment
    : ( LineCommentHash
      | LineCommentExcl
      )
      -> skip
    ;

fragment LineCommentHash
    : '#' ~[\r\n]*
    ;

fragment LineCommentExcl
    : '!' ~[\r\n]*
    ;

fragment WrappedLine
    : '\\'
      ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
    ;

Newline
    : ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
      -> skip
    ;

Key
    : KeyLetterStart
      ( KeyLetter
      | Escaped
      )*
    ;

fragment KeyLetterStart
    : ~[ \t\r\n:=]
    ;

fragment KeyLetter
    : ~[\t\r\n:=]
    ;

fragment Escaped
    : '\\' .?
    ;

Equal
    : ( '\\'? ':'
      | '\\'? '='
      )
    ;

Value
    : ValueLetterBegin
      ( ValueLetter
      | Escaped
      | WrappedLine
      )*
    ;

fragment ValueLetterBegin
    : ~[ \t\r\n]
    ;

fragment ValueLetter
    : ~ [\r\n]+
    ;

Whitespace
    : [ \t]+
      -> skip
    ;
```

My test file is this one:

```
# comment 1
# comment 2
# 
.key1= value1
key2\:sub=value2
key3 \= value3

key4=value41\
value42

# comment3
#comment4
key=value
```

When I run `grun`, I'm getting following output:

```
[@0,30:42='.key1= value1',<Value>,4:0]
[@1,45:60='key2\:sub=value2',<Value>,5:0]
[@2,63:76='key3 \= value3',<Value>,6:0]
[@3,81:102='key4=value41\\r\nvalue42',<Value>,8:0]
[@4,130:138='key=value',<Value>,13:0]
[@5,141:140='<EOF>',<EOF>,14:0]
```

I don't understand why the `Value` definition is matched. When commenting out the `Value` definition, however, it recognizes the `Key` and `Equal` definitions:

```
[@0,30:34='.key1',<Key>,4:0]
[@1,35:35='=',<Equal>,4:5]
[@2,37:42='value1',<Key>,4:7]
[@3,45:49='key2\',<Key>,5:0]
[@4,50:50=':',<Equal>,5:5]
[@5,51:53='sub',<Key>,5:6]
[@6,54:54='=',<Equal>,5:9]
[@7,55:60='value2',<Key>,5:10]
[@8,63:68='key3 \',<Key>,6:0]
[@9,69:69='=',<Equal>,6:6]
[@10,71:76='value3',<Key>,6:8]
[@11,81:84='key4',<Key>,8:0]
[@12,85:85='=',<Equal>,8:4]
[@13,86:93='value41\',<Key>,8:5]
[@14,96:102='value42',<Key>,9:0]
[@15,130:132='key',<Key>,13:0]
[@16,133:133='=',<Equal>,13:3]
[@17,134:138='value',<Key>,13:4]
[@18,141:140='<EOF>',<EOF>,14:0]
```

but how to let it recognize the `Key`, `Equal` **and** `Value` definitons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR's lexer rules match as much characters as possible, that is why you're seeing all these `Value` tokens being created (they match the most characters).

[Lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes) seem like a good fit to use here. Something like this:

```
lexer grammar PropertiesLexer;

COMMENT
 : [!#] ~[\r\n]* -> skip
 ;

KEY
 : ( '\\' ~[\r\n] | ~[\r\n\\=:] )+
 ;

EQUAL
 : [=:] -> pushMode(VALUE_MODE)
 ;

NL
 : [\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

mode VALUE_MODE;

  VALUE
   : ( ~[\\\r\n] | '\\' . )+
   ;

  END_VALUE
   : [\r\n]+ -> skip, popMode
   ;
```